# Startup up Logo window - Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have written a swing application in Java and want to display the logo of the application at program start-up for a couple of seconds before the actual program GUI appears. How do you think I can do this in swing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A built-in Splash-Screen Functionality was added in Java SE 6, take a look [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/splashscreen/) .

Answer (score 3):

You can use SplashScreen: SplashScreen.getSplashScreen().setImageURL(imageURL)

If it does not meet your requirements for some reason you can either create instance of java.awt.Window or javax.swing.JWindow and put image at the middle of the window. Use Timer to disappear this window after specific timeout.

You can also use Frame or JFrame and call its `f.setUndecorated(false)`